# Parsing a string using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

So I want the input of argparse to be a string instead of the command line.
for example:

```
python3 some_script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I want to give the argparse the string `"arg1 arg2 arg3"`

```
import argparse
command = "arg1 arg2 arg3"
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# add args here
args = parser.parse_args()
# process the command here and extract values
```

Comment: thanks it worked, using `parser.parse_args( ["script", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"] )` did exactly what I wanted.
it was mantioned here all along 
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#parsing-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list directly in `parse_args()`

```
args = parser.parse_args(["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"])
```

or you can use your line

```
command = "arg1 arg2 arg3"
args = parser.parse_args(command.split(" "))
```

You can always put it in `sys.argv` and `parser` should use it

```
import sys

sys.argv = ["script", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
```

it can be useful if you want to `append()` some option to values which you get from command line

```
sys.argv.append("--debug")
```

---

If you have more complex `command` with quoted strings like

```
'arg1 "Hello World" arg3'
```

then you can use standard module [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to split it correctly into three arguments

```
import shlex
shlex.split('arg1 "Hello world" arg3')


['arg1', 'Hello World', 'arg3'].
```

Normal `command.split(" ")` would incorrectly give four arguments

```
['arg1', '"Hello', 'World"', 'arg3']
```