# How to parse a string in argparser during execution

Tags: python, argparse

I want to create a mini shell, so after i run my file,

```
python3 ./main.py
```

With whatever arguments I add, I then just constantly take input like a normal shell,

```
>> command
output
>> -s
output
>> ...
```

So I am just doing simple `while True: command = input()`, but these commands may take flags as well so stuff like

```
>> command -s -p -h
```

However I can't really parse these the same way as when I run the the first file. Is there a way to parse the `command -s -p -h` part again into argparser so I get the nice namespace?

I basically want my program to argparse normally when I run the main.py in the first place then be able to parse strings I create in the script, `x = input()` again in with the same format for running my main.py.

Comment: Have you searched on the site? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368666/parsing-a-string-using-argparse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.parse_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) can take an `args` argument with a list of strings to parse, for example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-s', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-p', action='store_false')
parser.add_argument('-h', action='store_true')

command = 'command -s -p -h'
command_name, *command_args = command.split()
command_args_parsed = parser.parse_args(args=command_args)
print(command_args_parsed)  # -> Namespace(h=True, p=False, s=True)
```

(The splitting here is just for example. You might be using something more thorough like [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).)

This is covered in the documentation here: [Parsing arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments)